# Specify style of div when hyperlink is being hovered over

Tags: css

With regard to the following markup:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="myimage.gif" /></a>
</div>
```

The `div.mydiv` is basically styled to be a pretty rounded edge box around the image specified within the link. Lets say its `background-color` starts as `black`.

I would like to make it so that when I `:hover` over `myimage.gif`, the style of `div.mydiv` changes the `background-color` to, lets say, `yellow`.

How can I specify the style of `div.mydiv` when a nested `<a>` is being hovered over?

Comment: I don't really know if it is possible to do it in CSS but you can do it easily with javascript.

Comment: You can't select up in pure CSS, you'll need Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`.mydiv:hover
{
background-color:yellow;
}`

in a CSS file, assuming you have one. I don't think there's a way to do this inline.

Comment: That will fire on `.mydiv:hover`, not `.mydiv:hover img`. The effect is triggering `.mydiv` from `.mydiv img` to have `background: yellow`, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. Sorry for not reading the question properly :-)

Comment: Actually - while I agree this wasn't 100% the perfect answer, it works exactly like I needed it to in this instance.  So, thank you very much :)